# c# list linq expression for 'x' equal to anything from another list?

Tags: c#, linq, list, select, lambda

I have a list of selected values and I want to see if my dataset contains any of these selected values, I know this can be done with linq but I am unsure how? This is what I have tried (the second line being where i am stuck)?

```
 List<ListItem> li = cbList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
 List<DataRow> dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any(r => r["id"].ToString() == **ANY_OF_LI.SELECTEDVALUE**).ToList();
```

Comment: `.someSelectedValues.Any( x => x==r["id"].ToString() )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
List<DataRow> dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    .Where(r => li.Select(listItem => listItem.Value)
                        .Contains(r["id"].ToString()))
                    .ToList();
```

Instead of `Any`, use `Where` and `Select` the value from list of selected items and use `Enumerable.Contains`.

Just a minor suggestion, If any value of `r["id"]` is `null` then you could end up with a NRE, so use:

```
.Contains(Convert.ToString(r["id"]))))
```

`Convert.ToString` will return an empty string in case of `null` value.

Comment: Wow perfect, still fairly new to linq queries so many thanks for your help +1 and will accept when it allows me to :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming r["id"].ToString() is what you're looking for in li, you could use [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<DataRow> dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any(r => li.Contains(r["id"].ToString()).ToList();
```